# How can I filter internal emails CCed with external ones using Gmail Filters? Or any other email filters for that matter

Tags: email, filter, gmail

I have a range of Gmail filters currently, 
I've so far been successful in filtering out most of my companies external emails.
But I'm looking to filter any internal emails that have been CCd with an external email address, and then put this in an external folder to be archived.

I do not want internal emails with no CCs to go into this folder.
Is there any way to achieve this?

I've tried so many different methods and none seem to work. Any ideas would be much appreciated. If you don't think it be done either then please put me out of my misery.

If you have any other suggestions for other email clients that can achieve this functionality then I'm all ears. All suggestions are much appreciated.

Thank you for your time.
Josh